# Is there an explicit mention of a curse by Damayanti on Kali in the given excerpt from the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, kali, curse, nala

Considered the following excerpt from Mahabharatha.

> And Nala upon becoming acquainted with the science of dice, Kali came
> out of his body, incessantly vomiting from his mouth the virulent
> poison of Karkotaka. And when Kali, afflicted (by Damayanti's curse)
> came out (of Nala's body), the fire of that curse also left Kali.
> Indeed, long had been the time for which the king had been afflicted
> by Kali, as if he were of unregenerate soul. And Kala the ruler of the
> Nishadhas, in wrath, was bent upon cursing Kali, when the latter,
> frightened, and trembling, said with joined hands, 'Control thy wrath,
> O king! I will render thee illustrious. **Indrasena's mother had
> formerly cursed me in anger when she had been deserted by thee.** Ever
> since that time undergoing sore affliction I resided in thee, O mighty
> monarch, O unconquered one, miserably and burning night and day with
> the venom of the prince of snakes. I seek thy protection. If thou dost
> not curse me who am affrighted and seek thy protection, then those men
> that will attentively recite thy history, shall be even free from fear
> on my account.' And thus addressed by Kali, king Nala controlled his
> wrath. And thereupon the frightened Kali speedily entered into the
> Vibhitaka tree. And while the Kali was conversing with Naishadha, he
> was invisible to others. And delivered from his afflictions, and
> having counted the fruits of that tree, the king, filled with great
> joy and of high energy, mounted on the car and proceeded with energy,
> urging those fleet horses. And from the touch of Kali the Vibhitaka
> tree from that hour fell into disrepute. And Nala, with a glad heart,
> began to urge those foremost of steeds which sprang into the air once
> and again like creatures endued with wings. And the illustrious
> monarch drove (the car) in the direction of the Vidarbhas. And after
> Nala had gone far away, Kali also returned to his abode. And abandoned
> by Kali, O king, that lord of earth, the royal Nala, became freed from
> calamity though he did not assume his native form.
>
> [[Section 72, Nalopakhyana Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03072.htm)

From Kali's bolded confession, it's evident that Damayanti played a role in his predicament. However, this raises an interesting question: Is the specific Damayanti's curse explicitly detailed elsewhere in the Mahabharata?